# What is the deepest part of the moon on the near side?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-base, crater

Per title, I must emphasize that it shall be on the near side. Antoniadi (lunar crater) and Aitken basin are all on the far side. Preferrably it is also wide and large like the Oceanus Procellarum...

Answer (score 15):

Looks like it's Hercules G, which is a crater nested inside the larger crater of Hercules. It's about 10 km across, and Hercules is about 45 km across.

You can look on the [LROC Quickmap](https://bit.ly/3baPsJD) for stuff like this. I created a link for you to the right area, and set up the layers to show topography. Explore the menus on the left for more stuff, it has all kinds of data. To see what the colors in the topography map mean, you can check the palette used for the layer. This is the WAC DTM Color Map, and there is a link to the palette at the bottom of it's section. Or, to make it easy. it's [here](https://files.actgate.com/quickmap/eyeball_pallette_scalebar_modscale.png), and I'll put in an image of both the crater and the palette.

[image: Topography of Hercules G, the lowest point on the near side of the moon]

[image: Pallette of the LROC topography map]

According to the colors, Hercules G is between 6210 and 6940 m below lunar 'sea level'. I didn't see anything lower, feel free to pan around in case there is something lower.

Comment: Thank you your 10km across description. May you tell the audience how you can tell? I may not need the data but in a worldbuilding scenario (worldbuilding scenario stackexchange, readers).

Comment: The depression experienced likely subzero degree Celsius coldness even with sunlight of a lunar day. Then human settlers can fill it with high molar mass liquid -- fluoropropane for example so the fluorocarbons are liquid in one whole lunar day. Then in a fantasy worldbuilding scenario, lunar tidal power can be exploited because the moon experience Earth's pull. By ratio of gravity, the force is six times stronger than Earth tides.

Comment: @Kav There is a scale in the bottom right corner of the screen. If you click on the little world in the top left, you can switch to Equidistant cylindrical, which is a bit better for estimating. Also there is a draw tool when you click on the search icon, that can be used for precise measurements. I did just a quick estimate.

Comment: @Kav That's a mighty ambitious scenario. If we set aside the gigantic difficulties of creating such a system, the idea of tidal power on the moon is titillating. Interesting idea.

Comment: @Kav Sorry, your tidal power scheme won't work. Firstly, even on Earth the tidal variation in the biggest lakes is quite small. [This NOAA page](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/gltides.html) says that the largest gravitational tide on the Great Lakes is <5 cm. But the Moon is tidally locked, so it experiences almost no tidal change due to the Earth over the course of the lunar day (~1 month), apart from a small effect due to [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration). There *would* be a small tide due to the Sun, but once again, it's on a monthly cycle.

Comment: @kimholder How were you able to earn so much upvotes? :)

Comment: @PM2Ring So, do you think ANY tidal power scheme will not work on the Moon? Tides on Earth are possible due to gravitational force full by the Moon. How about the other way around? Make no mistake: this is not the Newton's Third Law couple.

Comment: @Kav many hours of work over a number of years, like everyone with high points. I did work at it for a couple of years, as it's a great way to learn about space exploration. It was a good experience. About PM2Ring's comment, they're right. I didn't think about it before I made my comment. Your point that gravitational influence there is much higher is why the moon is tidally locked to us. Without it spinning on its axis such that the lake turns its surface away from the Earth and then back, its not going to have any tidal movement of significance. Size doesn't even really matter in that case.

Comment: @Kav I seriously doubt it. As I said before, you'd still get some solar tidal energy. On Earth the solar tidal force is almost 0.45 as strong as the lunar tidal force, but on the Moon the amount of *power* (energy / time) is reduced by about 1/30, due to the long lunar rotation period. You could ask a new question about this, either here or on Physics.SE. One of our resident rocket scientists, David Hammen, happens to know quite a lot about [tides](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A52112+tide)...

Comment: @David Hammen do you think ANY tidal power scheme will not work on the Moon?

Answer (score 11):

Following Kim Holder's advice to "pan around", there's also **Clavius D** (-58.7, -12.4), another embedded crater inside the larger Clavius.

It's one step lower in absolute elevation, in the -5400m to -6210m category, but the surrounding rim of Clavius is about 1.5km higher than Hercules, so possibly deeper depending on your definition.

[image: Clavius D]